# Nodepdf header images

Tags: node.js, pdf, sails.js, node-pdfkit

Right now I'm using nodepdf (https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodepdf) for server-side PDF generation. I'm trying to add an image to the header of the pages generated, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
var options = {
       'paperSize': {
                pageFormat: 'A4',
                'header': {
                        height: '5cm',
                        contents: headerHTML
                },
                'footer': {
                        height: '3.55cm',
                        contents: footerHTML
                 }
        }
};
```

headerHTML comes from something that looks like this:

```
res.render(url, options, function (err, html) {
        if (err) { d.reject(err); }

        d.resolve(html);
});
```

the header view:

```
<img style="width: 1cm; height: 1cm;" src="..." />
```

All of this is done through SailsJS.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: There is no image in the header.